# Confusion with Threaded binary tree

Tags: c, data-structures, tree

[image]

Hi all,

As per definition of Threaded binary tree given below

> A binary tree is threaded by making all right child pointers that would normally be null point to the inorder successor of the node, and all left child pointers that would normally be null point to the inorder predecessor of the node.

But in above diagram right child pointers pointing to inorder predecessor and left child pointer pointing to inorder successor ,that making me confuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at C, what is it's predecessor? Successor? The order is

```
B then C then D
```

So B is C's predecessor, D is C successor.

Where does C's left pointer point? B, that's the predecessor, seems good to me.

Likewise, as expected, C's right pointer points to D.

Seems like statement, diagram and logic all agree. Where's the problem?

Comment: Thanks @Djna got your point ,its fairly simple.what you are saying is C is node whose left pointer and right pointer are NULL and left pointer points to predecessor and left pointer point to successor.

Answer (score 1):

Both the quote and the graphic are correct, maybe you have your definition of successor and predecessor backward?

Answer (score 1):

No, they are pointing to the correct node.

Comment: yes ,they are pointing to correct node but how it really supporting the definition of Binary threaded tree that am able to understand??

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. Take G as an example, it's left child is F which is the inorder predecessor of the node. If that's still confusing check what inorder means.

Comment: thats fine but if you take E as an example it should only point to F not to D yet its pointing to D ,how can??

Comment: There is no null in a threaded tree. What is the inorder predecessor of E?

Comment: D is inorder predecessor of E

Answer (score 1):

In some books, when the authors refer to the '**left** child' they mean the child which appears to the **right** of the parent node, (presumably because it is to the left from the node's own point of view). The same applies the other way around - they refer to **right** as **left**

Be careful not to get confused!

In the diagram above, the definition is correct: the left child is referred as to as the left child.

The case of the right node is similar

Answer (score 0):

The definition and the graphic are consistent with each other. However, the following statement is false:

> But in above diagram right child pointers pointing to inorder
>   predecessor and left child pointer pointing to inorder successor